# Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool' Checkbox MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with `checkboxes` in MVC. I have a table with one column as `bit` type.The following code giving me an error.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(IEnumerable<City> cities) 
{ 
    if (cities.Count(x => x.Chosen) == 0)
    {
        return "You did not select any city"; 
    }

    ......
}
```

Chosen is a bit type here. and when I am trying to build it says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Is `x.Chosen` type of `bool?`?

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explainary. Your `x.Chosen` is `bool?` type (`Nullable<bool>`).

It mean you should first check it on `null`. like this for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(IEnumerable<City> cities) 
{ 
    if (cities.Count(x => x.Chosen.HasValue && x.Chosen.Value) == 0)
    {
        return "You did not select any city"; 
    }

    ......
}
```

It's even better to write like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(IEnumerable<City> cities) 
{ 
    if (!cities.Any(x => x.Chosen.HasValue && x.Chosen.Value))
        return "You did not select any city"; 
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because the field Chosen is nullable in your database & it is non nullable in your model. To overcome this

```
[HttpPost]
public string Index(IEnumerable<City> cities) 
{ 
    if (cities.Count(x => x.Chosen.Value) == 0)
    {
        return "You did not select any city"; 
    }
}
```

or else change the field Chosen in your model as nullable. For Ex.

```
public bool? Chosen { get; set; }
```

then you can simply use

```
if (cities.Count(x => x.Chosen) == 0)
```